# boost asio resolver failed to resolve valid host

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Example of host is

```
www.somethingValidAndAccessibleFromBrowser.com
```

I have many threads, every thread has it's own io_service (and resolver of course) and threads may resolve same hosts.

Comment: And what is the error you get? How do you check the host? Also, are you checking the string you show verbatim, including the `/something` (which is not part of the hostname)?

Comment: something really wrong in my code ... must look at it, thanks

Comment: Bad logs, I was resolving it without query

Answer (score 0):

Resolving can't be done in parallel, must use mutex. That's the solution.